# Путан(н)ые следы. Две Н или одна?

Tags: грамматика, удвоенные-буквы

Путанные следы или путаные следы?

Answer (score 4):

**Путаные следы.**

В суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишется **нн**; как правило, эти причастия **имеют приставки или пояснительные слова**: ***ис***правленная рукопись; правленные **корректором** гранки.
**При отсутствии приставок или пояснительных слов пишется одно н**; ср.: *замощённые дороги — мощённые булыжником дороги — мощёные дороги*. В этом случае перед нами прилагательное, образованное от страдательного причастия прошедшего времени: *правленый текст, бешеный волк, вяленая вобла, глаженые брюки, драная куртка, золочёные изделия, ломаная линия, путаный ответ, рваная рана, сеяные травы, стираное бельё и т. п.*

Более подробно можете почитать, например, у Д.Э. Розенталя, в параграфе "Правописание *нн* и *н* в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных". На просторах Интернета справочник имеется.